# How to print a 0 in front of a decimal when the value is 0.98

Tags: java, decimalformat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

In this case, when my value is 0.98 it is displaying .98 rather than 0.98
What should I tweak in my DecimalFormat?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: What happens if value is `1` it displays `1.00` so have a guess what `0` and `#` stand for (one is always show)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the last `#` with a `0`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
```